# Java Apache FTP: Can connect but can't upload

Tags: java, ftp

I'm using this code in JAVA

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try 
    {
        client.connect("ftp.serverapp.amon-internet.com");
        client.login("u780746385", "serverapp");
        //client.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
        //client.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE); 
        //client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        //
        // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
        //
        String filename = "test.txt";
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

        //
        // Store file to server
        //
        client.storeFile(filename, fis);
        client.logout();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (fis != null) 
            {
                fis.close();
            }

            client.disconnect();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So it can connect, but when it tries to upload my files, it says:

```
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__send(FTP.java:505)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:479)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:608)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.port(FTP.java:932)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:812)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:633)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(FTPClient.java:624)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:1976)
at Waar.Waar.<init>(Waar.java:67)
at Waar.Waar.main(Waar.java:626)
```

I just want to say that with the Microsoft librairie with in C# it works with the same exact FTP server.

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work in JAVA ?

Thanks :)

EDIT: I finally found the problem. The Windows' firewall is blocking Java from accessing a FTP server, I used this code to get put an exception everytime my application is runned by someone

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) 
        {
             line = reader.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: is this on a local network? Over the internet, you probably need `client.enterLocalPassiveMode();`

Comment: Passive mode is needed to ftp from _behind_ a NAT router to an internet server.  This is because a new connection is needed every time data needs to be transferred.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's over the internet and when I use client.enterLocalPassiveMode() it says that the permission is denied